# How to .setStroke(BasicStroke)?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I've got the following problem: I want to create a new BasicStroke and set it on a Graphics2D object. This is the code I wrote for that problem:

```
    BasicStroke stil = new BasicStroke(zo.getLinienbreite(),
        BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
    g2d.setStroke(stil);
```

But next to the error that *the constructor BasicStroke(float, int, int) is undefined* (which actually isn't if I'm reading the documentation right), it says that "*The method setStroke(Stroke) in the type Graphics2D is not applicable for the arguments (BasicStroke)*".

Comment: What is `zo.getLinienbreite()` and why are you passing that into the BasicStroke constructor?

Comment: 2) Do you have your own class named `BasicStroke` anywhere near this class?

Comment: zo.getLinienbreite()
is a method of the object zo which gives back the width of the line, so the BasicStroke knows how width the line should be.

I've got no other BasicStroke near this class, it's actually my first and only try with Strokes.

Answer (score 0):

One of the [`BasicStroke` constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html#BasicStroke(float,%20int,%20int)) takes a float and two int's. I'm guessing `zo.getLinienbreite()` is not a float, so you'll either have to explicitly cast it

```
BasicStroke stil = new BasicStroke( (float)zo.getLinienbreite(), ...
```

or change it to float in `zo`'s class. Once that's done, the next error will disappear.

Cheers,

Comment: Sorry, but zo.getLinienbreite() is a float. Eclipse also tells me that BasicStroke(float, int, int) is undefined. That's why I'm wondering. And even if I use another construcor

    g2d.setStroke(stil);

wont work.

Comment: Are you using some weird/old JDK version? We need more info to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. Turns out that I used `com.sun.prism.BasicStroke` instead of the import `java.awt.BasicStroke`.
Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it seems that Eclipse uses this by default